# Module not found: Can't resolve 'uuid/v4'

Tags: javascript, json, uuid, react.js

I am a beginner in React programming and I was following this tutorial in Youtube: https://youtu.be/hQAHSlTtcmY and everything went well until it was required to install uuid library and after that when I run the page I get an error saying: "Failed to compile.

./src/App.js

Module not found: Can't resolve 'uuid/v4' in 'C:\Users\username\reactnative\src'" so can anyone help me fix this error? And also there are no other errors in the code and it's exactly the same as shown in the video!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install uuid library via node package manager i.e. `npm`

```
npm install uuid
```

Then import uuidv4 from uuid library

```
   const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

Inside function:

```
  setTodo(prevTodo => {

    return [...prevTodo,{id:uuidv4(), name: name, complete:false}]
  })
```

Comment: What does Yarn mean? And I added the import and function commands but same issue.

Comment: Yarn  is another package manager for node js. I have edited the answer. check this out

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem learning from the same tutorial from WebDevSimplified. 
For me the following worked fine (i.e., with `import`):

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

See [Hoàng Vũ Tgtt's answer to «Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61803504/12501050)
on Stack Overflow.